# Ошибка выполнения цикла bash

Tags: linux, bash, while

Доброго времени суток, коллеги.

Есть файл, содержащий в себе строки вида "hostname ip password"

Есть следующий bash-скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="/root/hostippasswd"
while read line
do

        NAME=$( echo $line | awk '{print $1}' )
        IP=$( echo $line | awk '{print $2}' )
        PWD=$( echo $line | awk '{print $3}' )
        echo $NAME
        echo $IP
        echo $PWD
        VERSION=$( sshpass -p $PWD ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$IP 'uname -a' )
#       echo $VERSION
#echo "$line"
done < $FILE
```

Если первые несколько ip|паролей не валидны - всё ок, цикл продолжается. Как только происходит первое успешное соединение с сервером - я получаю ответ от "uname -a" и скрипт завершается.

Почему так, и как заставить скрипт отрабатывать файл hostippasswd до конца?

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался.

Цикл ломал ssh. Мне, пока что,не удалось выяснить зачем, но ssh после подключения читает stdin. А так как у меня в stdin лежит файл со списком серверов, то ssh дочитывает его до конца и цикл завершается.

Из мануала к SSH:

> -n Redirects stdin from /dev/null (actually, prevents reading from stdin). This must be used when ssh is run in the background

Поэтому опция -n помогла.

Answer (score 1):

Доброй ночи.

Может ssh кидает сигнал, который воспринимается как завершение цикла.

Я для автологина на сервера, где нет "ключевого" доступа, использую **expect**.

В вашем случае попробуйте сабшелл :

```
#!/bin/bash
...

sshpass -p "$PWD" \
| ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@"$IP" 'uname -a' \
| tee output.log &

...
# End of script
```

Comment: Увы, нет, сабшелл не помог. Всё равно выпадает из цикла.

Comment: Разобрался. Оказалась весьма оригинальная проблема - см мой ответ.

Comment: @AlexandrBlinov Да интересно, думаю себе тоже пригодится на будущее. Спасибо за вопрос, не из песочницы!