# создал bash script для проверки обновлений, надо его улучшить, чтоб сначала выводил название сервера, потом список возможных обновлений

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
while read P
do
ssh "$P" /usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check -p && sudo apt-get upgrade --dry-run
done < ~/iplist1
```

должно виглядеть так:

название сервера: serv1 
"возможные обноления"
название сервера: serv2 
"возможные обноления"....

Comment: 1. часть команды после оператора `&&` выполняется локально. 2. вы напишите (прямо в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit]) **в чём именно** у вас трудности.

Comment: вы не знаете, куда вставить вызов `echo`? попробуйте перед вызовом `ssh`.

Comment: знаю,но если там написать echo,то оно сработает только 1 раз,а мне надо чтоб перед каждым сервером писало

Comment: ну так у вас [всего один раз цикл и выполняется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/737631/178576). причём часть после оператора `&&` выполняется **локально**.

Comment: Может для таких штук лучше юзать чё-нить из мира системного администрирования? Например `ansible` или `puppet`? Дальше костылей будет только больше.